# How can I check If element is behind element with position fixed?

Tags: javascript, position

I have a problem.
I made a custom mouse cursor(using div with position fixed that follow the real cursor).
And I have text in h2 tag that should change on mouse hover.
But now it doesn't work.
Is there a way how to fix this problem?

I tried to make functions in javascript that react on hover.
I also tried to use paramater onmouseover with function in it.

Comment: Give the DIV `pointer-events: none` style, then the mouse events will pass through it to the underlying element.

Comment: Is there a  reason to create a div element? -`element.style.cursor` supports `url( imageURL)` values to directly set the cursor to a custom image if that is the goal.